# Gradle project refresh failed

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

After upgrading to Android Studio v0.2.0, the following error message appeared.

[image]

Also, after few seconds my android studio closed itself and problem persists even if I create new android project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a reported issue in Android Studio Build #AI-130.737825, built on July 11, 2013.
Luckily, there is a workaround that you can do to fix this import issue.

> Externally edit the project's build.gradle file, changing 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.2' to 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.0'

[Here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57533) is the link to the issue.

@Xav, have already mentioned that in new release 0.5.+ the issue is automatically fixed.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to your project folder like so
   [image]
2. Open the file build.gradle in any text editor.
3. Under `dependencies`

   change to `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.0'`

Comment: Thanks for the useful edition coding crow after doing that what you suggest this error is occurs http://postimg.org/image/lqxbkypv5/

Comment: @Adi If this problem is solved, you may accept the answer. Restart Android Studio. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/17614477/932307 for your new problem. If problem persists ask a new question and leave a comment here.

Comment: The dependency should be 0.5.+ to automatically pick updates. We've already released 0.5.1 to fix something.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this on http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio020released

> "To install 0.2, you'll need to install a new Studio bundle. In other
>   words, we are not offering a patch update from 0.1.9 to 0.2. The
>   reason for that is that we have made changes to for example the
>   bundled SDK such that it includes a pre-configured local Maven
>   repository which can serve up the v4 support library."

So you need to uninstall and reinstall Android Studio to upgrade to 0.2.