# Gradle: FAILURE: Could not determine which tasks to execute

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

Upgraded to Android Studio 0.2.0  and got the following [error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17613951/932307). The error got resolved after applying suggested solution but now the following error appeared.

```
Gradle: 
FAILURE: Could not determine which tasks to execute.
* What went wrong:
Task 'assemble' not found in root project 'MerlinCheckProject'.
* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks.
```

I have no clue what the error is how to solve it. Appreciate help.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Remove `<component name="FacetManager"> ... </component>` from your `iml` file.

---

**From http://tools.android.com/knownissues**:

If you get the following error message:

> Gradle: 
>   FAILURE: Could not determine which tasks to execute.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Task 'assemble' not found in root project 'MyProject'.
> - Try:
>     Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks.

The real problem is that previous version of Android Studio misconfigured the IDEA file (e.g. `MyProject.iml`) -- it added an extra `<component name="FacetManager">` XML element that shouldn't be present. In the case above, the solution is to edit `MyProject.iml` and to remove the `<component name="FacetManager">` part as shown here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module external.system.id="GRADLE" type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="FacetManager">
    ...remove this element and everything inside such as <facet> elements...
  </component>
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    ...keep this part...
  </component>
</module>
```

Alternatively you could remove the project's `.idea` folder and `iml` files and re-import your sources into a new Android Studio project.

In the next release we'll fix this -- there will be a "fix this" button to do that fix automatically for you.

Comment: Like Bill1550 below, deleting this section of the .iml file didn't fix the problem for me. I had to delete the entire .idea directory and re-import the project as a gradle project to get builds working again.

Comment: I had a dependent lib(Facebook), i have to change both the .iml file from an external editor(TextEdit) to work it through.

Comment: This works like a charm. Just make sure to do the same thing on all .iml files (project root and modules).

Comment: This solution worked for me, although it is worth mentioning from another solution below, it did seem to require deleting the <componenet name="FacetManager"> element, and then *closing the project and reopening* before a successful compile.  Simply deleting the element (and even saving) did not solve the issue, only after closing and reopening did the compile execute.

Comment: Finally found correct solution for this issue. Thanks Matthias, you the man!

Comment: @Matthias Robbers It worked! Thank you Matthias. Just one question, did you ever get to making that "fix this" button.

Comment: Thanks a lot .. got the problem resolved with the alternative solution of removing the project's .idea folder and .iml files and re-importing the sources into a new Android Studio project.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, in a cordova project, I had an old gradle version 1.4 and that was the problem. 
So try to remove gradle

```
sudo apt-get remove gradle
```

then, download new binary relase of gradle from [here](https://gradle.org/releases/) . I got v3.5.1.
Finally, Create a directory for the Gradle installation.

```
sudo mkdir /opt/gradle
```

Extract the downloaded archive to the newly created directory.

```
sudo unzip -d /opt/gradle gradle-3.5.1-bin.zip
```

Configure the PATH environment variable so that the gradle executable can be directly executed anywhere on the system.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/gradle/gradle-3.5.1/bin
```

You can run the following command to check if the Gradle install was successful.

```
gradle -v
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The recommended way to install gradle under linux is using sdk, see https://gradle.org, I did the following steps:
sudo apt install zip    ## zip required by SDKman, see http://sdkman.io/
## do the following steps as the user who wants to use the tools NOT root!
curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash    ## SDKman recommended option to install *up-to-date* gradle, see https://gradle.org/install/
source "/root/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"     ## set env to use sdk without opening a new shell
sdk install gradle 4.6
Oops, line breaks are killed in comments ...

Answer (score 4):

Deleting the facet-manager component from IML file did not solve the problem for me.  I got the same error and closing and reopening the project caused the facet-manager component to be recreated in the iml file.

I had to delete the .idea directory and the .iml file and then import the top level gradle.build file to solve the problem.  I was able to import the project in place using the import option on the initial Android Studio menu (with no project open).

Comment: You can leave a comment for @matthias in his answer.

Comment: @coding crow: Actually he can't. He does not not have enough reputation (50). I don't understand why you can answer everywhere but not comment everywhere. Anyway, the solution from this answer is already mentioned at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @matthias I never knew this. Here http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/a/2412 is one possible explaination.

Answer (score 1):

The solution works fine. If you're having issues with it, ensure you close Android Studio completely, then edit the file, then reopen it.

Answer (score 0):

I am a Windows user. The solution that worked for me was to remove the previous version of Android Studio:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html#Updating

Comment: You can leave a comment in @matthias answer if the suggested solution does not work for you on windows. It works in Ubuntu for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the answer from @Dhafer.Dhib to check the installed gradle version, I want to add: The recommended way to install gradle under linux is using sdk, see https://gradle.org, I did the following steps:

```
sudo apt install zip    ## zip required by SDKman, see http://sdkman.io/
## do the following steps as the user who wants to use the tools NOT root!
curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash    ## SDKman recommended option to install *up-to-date* gradle, see https://gradle.org/install/
source "/root/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"     ## set env to use sdk without opening a new shell
sdk install gradle 4.6
gradle -v
```