# Android Studio staying on Gradle build using tasks

Tags: android, android-studio

I have started using Android Studio on Windows 7.  Created a simple app and have deployed it to my phone (via USB) and on the emulator numerous times without any problems.

All of a sudden I am not able to deploy my app anymore.  When I open Android Studio a message at the bottom says: "Gradle build using tasks: [clean, :ProjectName:assembleDebug]"  This process just keeps running for ever preventing me from doing anything in Android Studio.

This message does not go away and I am not able to do anything.  Has anyone experienced this before?  Seems Eclipse might be a better option for me...

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is that previous version of Android Studio misconfigured the IDEA file (e.g. `MyProject.iml`). It added an extra `<component name="FacetManager">` XML element that shouldn't be present.

In the case above, the solution is to edit `MyProject.iml` and remove the `<component name="FacetManager">` part as shown here:

```
<module external.system.id="GRADLE" type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="FacetManager">
    ...remove this element and everything inside such as <facet> elements...
  </component>
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    ...keep this part...
  </component>
</module>
```

See also [Gradle: FAILURE: Could not determine which tasks to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614477/gradle-failure-could-not-determine-which-tasks-to-execute).