# Android Studio 0.4.3 - Unable to compile official Android Samples

Tags: android, compiler-errors, gradle, android-studio

I've got Android Studio 0.4.3 installed on my system and try to import and run the official samples from the Android Developers site:

http://developer.android.com/samples/index.html

Unfortunately when I try to compile I get the following error:

> FAILURE: Could not determine which tasks to execute.
>
> - What went wrong: Task 'assemble' not found in root project 'ActionBarCompat-Basic'.
> - Try: Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks.

As you can see I tried to compile the ActionBarCompat-Basic example, but the result is the same for all samples.

I already tried to delete the `<component name="FacetManager"> ... </component>` 
from my `iml` file and deleted the `.idea` folder like suggested in this thread:

[Gradle: FAILURE: Could not determine which tasks to execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614477/gradle-failure-could-not-determine-which-tasks-to-execute)

This did not solve the problem. After removal of the files I imported the project to Android Studio and tried to compile. As a consequence the `iml` file and the `.idea` folder are generated again and the error message stays the same.

Anyone else got this problem? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sample projects are using old version of gradle plugin which is no longer supported by Android Studio 0.4.3

Please do the following changes

Go to your module's `build.gradle`(like ActionBarCompat-BasicSample/build.gradle) file inside the project and replace dependency classpath at beginning by this

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
```

Change  the `distrubutionUrl` in `ActionBarCopat-Basic/gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties` file to this

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.9-all.zip
```

If you are using gradle version 1.10 replace `0.7.+ to 0.8.+` and `1.9 to 1.10` in above configurations .

I am assuming you have already removed component FacetManager from ActionBarCopat-Basic.iml file and re-imported the project.

This worked perfectly for me.

Comment: It also worked perfectly for me! Thank you for your fast reply!!! 
I was almost giving up...